# JS - having difficulties allowing whitespaces with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having problems allowing white spaces in js with regex.
I am not sure what it is, but I have been searching and not able to find an answer that works.

I am really new to regex, so please be kind for being ignorant of something this simple.

Here is my allowed characters currently:
`var validChar = /^[A-Z0-9]+$/i;`
If I add a space in it, it will not work: `/^[A-Z 0-9]+$/i`

What do I have to do in order to make it recognize a space?

Comment: Do you want \s ? That is the space (tab, whitespace, etc) character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Space character in regexp is defined like "**\s**":

```
/^[A-Z0-9\s]+$/i
```

Answer (score 1):

Add white space in last,like this   `var validChar = /^[A-Z0-9\s]+$/i;`